# OpenCV: draw contours of objects in the binary image

Tags: python, opencv

Following an example provided at http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html
, I use python in Spyder environment to draw contours of detected components in a binary image. My codes are here:

```
im = cv2.imread('test.jpg') #raw RGB image
im2 = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #gray scale image
plt.imshow(im2,cmap = 'gray')
```

The image is shown as follows:

[image]

Then,

```
thresh, im_bw = cv2.threshold(im2, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) #im_bw: binary image
im3, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(im_bw,cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv2.drawContours(im2, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
plt.imshow(im2,cmap='gray')  #without the code, only an array displayed in the console
```

These codes do not give a figure with contours for some reason. But if I change the last two lines of codes as follows:

```
cv2.drawContours(im, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
plt.imshow(im,cmap='gray')
```

It yields a figure with contour:

[image]

I feel confused about how these codes work? Does cv2.drawCoutours only apply to GRB images? Hope not.
Besides, it is noted that contours[0] gives a 3D array:

```
idx = contours[0]
print idx.shape

(392L, 1L, 2L)
```

the idx should store the pixel coordinates of all contour points. But how to interpret what each dimension represents, and get pixel coordinates for each contour point from it? Then I can use these coordinates to draw contours without resorting to cv2.drawContours

Answer (score 5):

The confusion is caused by the fact that **cv2.findContours can only be applied** **to binary** images whereas **cv2.drawContours to RGB**. That is why to draw contours, you need to convert im2 into RGB, then draw your contour, and then convert im2 into binary (GRAY) again. But what is really spooky, the outcome will not look the way you expect: your contour pixels look gray instead of white (which means that their values are somewhere in the region of 150-170 rather than 255). It can be remedied very easily: im2[im2!=0]=255.

```
im_gray = cv2.imread('test.jpg',0)
im_color=cv2.imread('test.jpg',1)
im3, contours, hierarchy = 
cv2.findContours(im_gray,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv2.drawContours(im_color, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
im = cv2.cvtColor(im_color, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# if you plot im now you will see grey contours not white
im[im!=0]=255
# all contours are white now!
```

Answer (score 3):

Both cv2.findContours and cv2.drawContours are destructive methods, which modify the original input image, and the latter is only applicable to RBG images for plotting, which explain that no visible contours are displayed in a plotted grayscale image.

Besides cv2.drawContours, the contour can be also easily drawn with using the indices of border pixels that are stored in "contours" (in the code above) obtained by cv2.findContours.

Comment: note from the opencv 3.4.4 documents (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html):

"Since OpenCV 3.2, findContours() no longer modifies the source image but returns a modified image as the first of three return parameters."